# I get "assertion 'g_atomic_int_get (&loop->ref_count) > 0' failed" errors out of the blue, even when no code is being executed

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, ubuntu

Full error message:

```
GLib-CRITICAL **: g_main_loop_is_running: assertion 'g_atomic_int_get (&loop->ref_count) > 0' failed
Segmentation fault

Process returned 139 (0x8B)
```

I'm writing a c++11 program on ubuntu.

From what I could read, it has something to do with binary reading. It does occur when I try to load a file. What is perplexing is that it consistently throws that error when I try to open one file, but it consistently manages to open another. What's even more perplexing is that sometimes that error is thrown when a popup window is shown, while no code is being executed.

All that being said, my code for reading ints looks like this(in header):

```
int ri(std::ifstream& _in)
        {
        int _i;
        _in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&_i),_intsize);
        return _i;
        };
```

I believe that's the only relevant code, as the crash apparently happens at random times during the loading process. It might also have something to do with stack overflowing, but the above error message is the only one I get out of the console.

Comment: What do popup windows have to do with this?  Also, what does "while no code is being executed" mean?

Comment: Can you test to see if the error happens during the `_in.read()`, by printing a string to the console just before and just after that line?

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune what I mean is that the program has GUI and I open a notification popup with OK button - during it the program is frozen and doesn't continue execution until the OK button is pressed. But, for some reason, it occasionally crashes after the popup shows, but before the button is pressed.


It doesn't actually crash immediately after _in.read(), there's always complete pairs of console outputs. But there doesn't seem to be one single place at which it crashes.

Actually, there seems to be two of them, at the first one it crashes only sometimes. I might be on to something.

Comment: OK, that's a whole bunch of ideas, presented in random order :) .  If you combine them in the original post (click "edit" under the row of tags), then readers will be more likely to understand what the real problem is and offer useful help!